# How select rows which contains at least one value from other table and is not equal? TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, ssms

As per subject, I have a problem with query. Problems occurs because table is not normalized. Schema of DB looks like:

Table A Columns:

```
ID - A,A,B,B,C,D (not unique)

AR - "N10 N12", "N1 N2 N3", "N1"
```

AR in A table is char(100)

ARID in AWS table is char(6)

The result from subselect is a column, with rows of chars. It can be inserted in a temporary table, but I suppose any other variable type can't store it.

It's simplified example, I want to select all rows where AR contains at least N1. In real case I have a lot of values to find in AR column, from other table.

I tried:

Contains - it will work, but @table variable can't be used with this statement

Inner Join and subquery in query - generally it works, but it's problem, it returns only rows where values are equals. For example, when I'm selecting for N1 it will be returned, but "N1 N2 N3" not and it should be in results.

My actual query:

```
select * 
from A 
where AR in (select ARID 
             From AWS 
             group by ARID 
             having count(*)>2) 
order by EvaluationTime desc
```

Thanks and Regards,
B.

Comment: Please tag your dbms, and what data type is AR?  Text, JSON, Array?

Comment: dbms: sql-server, postgres, oracle, sql-server-2005, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two tables with the values you've provided (tell me if there are more), you'll first need a way to split the values in A.AR into manageable strings.  I use this User Defined Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_StringDelimiter]
/*********************************************************
**  Takes Parameter "LIST" and transforms it for use    **
**  to select individual values or ranges of values.    **
**                                                      **
**  EX: 'This,is,a,test' = 'This' 'Is' 'A' 'Test'       **
*********************************************************/
    (
          @LIST             VARCHAR(8000)
         ,@DELIMITER        VARCHAR(255)
    )

RETURNS @TABLE TABLE 
    ( 
         [RowID] INT IDENTITY
        ,[Value] VARCHAR(255)
    )
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
         @LISTLENGTH AS SMALLINT
        ,@LISTCURSOR AS SMALLINT
        ,@VALUE AS VARCHAR(255)
    ;
    SELECT 
         @LISTLENGTH = LEN(@LIST) - LEN(REPLACE(@LIST,@DELIMITER,'')) + 1
        ,@LISTCURSOR = 1
        ,@VALUE = ''
    ;
    WHILE @LISTCURSOR <= @LISTLENGTH
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @TABLE (Value)
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN @LISTCURSOR < @LISTLENGTH
                    THEN SUBSTRING(@LIST,1,PATINDEX('%' + @DELIMITER + '%',@LIST) - 1)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(@LIST,1,LEN(@LIST))
            END
        ;
        SET @LIST = STUFF(@LIST,1,PATINDEX('%' + @DELIMITER + '%',@LIST),'')
        ;       
        SET @LISTCURSOR = @LISTCURSOR + 1
        ;
    END
    ;
    RETURN
    ;
END
;
```

Then, with those two tables:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID CHAR(1), AR VARCHAR(55));
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('A','N1 N3 N4');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('B','N2');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('C','N1');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('D','N5');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('E','N2 N1');

DECLARE @TABLE2 TABLE (RowID INT IDENTITY, ARID VARCHAR(55));
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 (ARID) VALUES ('N1');
```

Using a `CROSS APPLY` and `LEFT JOIN`, I get the responses:

```
SELECT A.ID AS [A.ID], A.AR AS [A.AR],B.ARID AS [B.ARID]
FROM @TABLE A
CROSS APPLY dbo.UDF_StringDelimiter(A.AR,' ') X
INNER JOIN @TABLE2 B
    ON B.ARID = X.Value
ORDER BY ID
;
```

Returns:

```
A.ID     A.AR       B.ARID
-----------------------------------
A       N1 N3 N4     N1
C       N1           N1
E       N2 N1        N1
```

Of course you could also group this, return it as a delimited list, etc.  Give me more details and maybe I can give you a better response.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I tried your solution, it works partially, I suppose I changed something wrong. In the last column, where should be ARIDs separately, I have NULLs generally. When in A.AR is one value then B.ARID looks correctly, but when there is at least two values, then B.ARID is NULL.

Comment: That's surprising, since the example data I created includes single, double, and multiple values in `A.AR.` (Variable `@TABLE`).  If you just run `SELECT * FROM dbo.UDF_StringDelimiter(A.AR,' ')`, what do you get?

Comment: Are there actually values in A.AR that don't exist in B.ARID?

Comment: When I change left join to inner join query returns correct values, but only this which has one value in AR column in A table. Running query which you paste, I'm receiving "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 60
The multi-part identifier "A.AR could not be bound.". There shouldn't be values in A.AR which doesn't exist in B.ARID, but it can be in reverse way - can exist values in B.ARID which are not in A.AR.

Comment: But you only want to return values that exist in A.AR, correct?

Comment: Exactly. Example: In A.AR we have rows: "N1 N3 N4", "N2", "N1","N5","N2 N1". In B.ARID we have one row: "N1". I need to see all rows from A, which contains "N1", so it should be 1,3,5 row from A table.

Comment: Edited my answer to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.  With the example data you just gave me in your comments, it works here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2 tables, CROSS APPLY is your friend.

```
create  table #ARID(id varchar(10), ar varchar(100));
insert into #ARID values
('a', 'n1 n2'),
('a', 'n10 n11'),
('b', 'n1'),
('b', 'n11 n13 15'),
('c', 'n3'),
('c', 'n14 n12');
```

This is the table that contains values to search:

```
create table #TO_SEARCH(val varchar(10))
insert into #TO_SEARCH values ('n10'), ('n11');
```

And this simple query returns each row that contains al least one of these values:

```
SELECT ca.*
FROM   #TO_SEARCH ts
CROSS APPLY  (SELECT id, ar
              FROM   #ARID
              WHERE ar LIKE ('%' + ts.val + '%')
             ) ca
```

You can invert the tables, the result is the same:

```
SELECT id, ar
FROM   #ARID
CROSS APPLY  (SELECT val from #TO_SEARCH) ts
WHERE ar LIKE ('%' + ts.val + '%')

+----+------------+
| id | ar         |
+----+------------+
| a  | n10 n11    |
+----+------------+
| a  | n10 n11    |
+----+------------+
| b  | n11 n13 15 |
+----+------------+
```

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/CUEU92118